# nodetool repair taking too much time

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-3.0, cassandra-2.1

To repair the entire cluster it is taking 20 days which is really more than the gc_grace_seconds. But, Im not expecting this kind delay to do the repair. My question, Is there any chance to reduce the repair to 7-8 days?

Comment: Provide more info on how many nodes, what is the size of data on each nodes. Are you using incremental or full repair (depends on C* version)? Provide "nodetool status" o/p

Comment: 84 nodes, 4 dc's, 200gb -300gb on each node and I'm doing full repairs.

Comment: look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29145818/what-options-are-there-to-speed-up-a-full-repair-in-cassandra

Comment: and here: http://cassandra-reaper.io/